# Reference for duality inducing bijections between subobjects and quotients?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, duality

I'm not the most category-theoretic person but I have run into the following statement in my work. Suppose we have a category duality $\mathcal F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$. For my needs you can probably assume that $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are as nice as you want but I think it suffices for them to be <s>locally small</s> well-powered and co-well-powered (so that the subobjects or quotient objects of a given object form a set, thank you, Zhen Lin). I believe that for any object $X$ in $\mathcal C$ such an $\mathcal F$ will induce a bijection between the subobjects of $X$ and the quotient objects of $\mathcal F(X)$ by simply sending the class of a monomorphism $\alpha$ to the class of the epimorphism $\mathcal F(\alpha)$. This appears semi-obvious and a detailed proof is easy to give but it is a bit longer than I'd like to put in my paper, since the subject is something else completely. So my question is: what would be a reference for a statement of this form, preferably in a textbook on category theory.

For context, I'd like to apply this when $\mathcal C$ is the category of finite posets, $\mathcal D$ is the category of finite distributive lattices and $\mathcal F$ is the [functor sending a poset to the the lattice of its order ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_representation_theorem#Functoriality). Also, the dual statement is, of course, the even more intuitive claim that a category equivalence induces bijections between sets of subobjects. A reference for that would also be nice but I'm hoping for the above precise form.

Comment: Locally small does not imply that the (isomorphism classes) of subobjects or quotient objects of a fixed object form a small collection. That is the condition of being (co)wellpowered, which is different.

Comment: @ZhenLin Right you are, thanks! What got me confused is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject#Definitions which says that "if the subobject-collection of every object is a set, the category is called *well-powered* or sometimes *locally small*". It made me assume "locally small" in the conventional sense would be enough since "morphisms forming a set" is kinda what we want. But it isn't, of course.

Comment: The usage of "locally small" to mean "well-powered" is pretty archaic, I think.  I'm surprised it's even mentioned on Wikipedia.

Comment: All one can say about a question like this is that you have picked up some very confused ideas about what category theory does.  Just because the *axiomatisation* of the subject is symmetric in the direction of the arrows does not mean that any *particular* category is dual in the sense you suggest or otherwise.  It would be best to formulate whatever argument you have in mind in non-categorical language and then try to understand how the components of that argument are captured by categorical ideas.